# w+ mode in fopen?

Tags: php

```
fopen($handle, 'w+');
```

I'm looking to open a .CSV file, read each row and do something with a database, and then truncate the .CSV file and write something like

> This file has been read.

w+ implies Read/write but the file is also truncated. So what's the point of the read if fopen w+ will just erase what's in it?

Comment: w+ actually enables you to write data to a file whilst also being able to seek to a previously written position and read it again. Might be useful for, like, database files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `a+`

From the documentation:

```
'w+'     Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
'a+'     Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
```

Answer (score 2):

Then use unlink($filename) after you've finished reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'c+' mode.

> Open the file for reading and writing. If the file does not exist, it is created. If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w'), nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x'). The file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you probably want to open the file in 'r' mode to read it. Then close it and reopen in 'w' mode to write the truncation message.

Comment: The point of w+ is that you can than read back anything that you have written, whereas you can't do that with just 'w'.  I have adjusted my answer above.