# php records erasing txt

Tags: php, addition, record

A registration form write the data to a txt file using this code:

```
<?
if( isset( $_GET['list'] ) AND $_GET['list'] != '' ) {
$listId = $_GET['list'];
}
$email = $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-email'];
$fname = isset( $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-fname'] ) ? $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-fname'] : '';
$lname = isset( $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-lname'] ) ? $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-lname'] : '';


$fp = fopen("newsletter_subscriptions.txt","w+");

fputs($fp, "email : ");
fputs($fp, $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-email']);

fputs($fp, "\nPrénom : ");
fputs($fp, $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-fname']);

fputs($fp, "\nNom : ");
fputs($fp, $_POST['widget-subscribe-form-lname']);

fclose($fp);

?>
```

My problem is that each new record erase the previous one. I want to keep all records in the txt file.
How to do it ?

Comment: skip the text file, use a db.

Comment: When will people _finally_ start reading the documentation of the functions they use? Your question is answered in there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [w+ mode in fopen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939847/w-mode-in-fopen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening the file in the wrong mode.  [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

'w+'    Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You want to append to the file, you should use:

'a+'    Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.

Change the `fopen` line to:

```
$fp = fopen("newsletter_subscriptions.txt","a+");
```

Answer (score 3):

[File open modes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> `w+` Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the **beginning** of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> `a+` Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the **end** of the file.

Comment: Not that slow; you'd already answered and deleted before I edited in the PHP Docs reference